# Single point crossover

Tags: matlab, crossover

I have two array(matrix with one row) `temp1` and `temp2` as follow:

```
temp1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
temp2=[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]
```

and I have an index `pn=3`. I need output as follows:

```
tempNew=[1 2 3 13 14 15 16 17 18]
```

i.e. how do I create `tempNew` such that all values on indices up to `pn` come from `temp1` and all values beyond index `pn` come from `temp2`?

Comment: `[temp1(1:pn),temp2(pn:end)]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
temp1=[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
temp2=[10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18]
pn=3;
tempNew = [temp1(1:pn),temp2(pn+1:end)]
tempNew =
     1     2     3    13    14    15    16    17    18
```

You use `pn` to create two temporary arrays to index both of your `tempX` arrays. Then simply concatenate them using square brackets.

Indexing always starts at `1` in MATLAB, so `1:pn` will give you the first `pn` values of an array. `end` signifies the end of an array, so `pn+1:end` will give you all values from index `pn+1` up to the last one of an array.